# How to optimize my indexes cron execution?

Tags: magento2, cron, optimization

I'm checking how to optimize my cron execution in the reindex action, and I saw the option to run the index job in a **separated process**.

How does it work? can it be helpful to optimize the execution?

[image: Magento 2 optimize indexes cron execution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having issues with the indexes cron execution and your server is CPU optimized, yes you can use a separate process for it.

> **use_separate_process** | Run this crongroup’s jobs in a separate PHP process

Reference: [Specifying Cron group options](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-ref.html#specify-cron-group-options)